# Simplifying with spherical harmonics

Tags: summation, correlation, legendre-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

I originally asked this on the physics Stack Exchange site, but perhaps it could be more easily answered here.

Given the definition of the correlation function for CMB temperature fluctuations as

$$ C\left(\theta\right) = \left\langle \frac{\delta T}{T}\left(\hat{n}_1\right) \frac{\delta T}{T}\left(\hat{n}_2\right) \right\rangle_{\hat{n}_1\cdot \hat{n}_2 = \cos\theta} ,$$

I should be able to simplify it to

$$ C\left(\theta\right) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \sum_{l=0}^\infty (2l + 1) \, C_l \, P_l\left(\cos\theta\right) $$

(where $P_l \left(x\right)$ are the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)) by decomposing the temperature fluctuations into [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) like this

$$ \frac{\delta T}{T} = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^l a_{lm} Y_{lm}. $$

I think the first step of this procedure should look like this

$$ C\left(\theta\right) = \left\langle \sum_{l_1=0}^\infty \sum_{m_1=-l_1}^{l_1} a_{l_1 m_1} Y_{l_1 m_1}\left(\hat{n}_1\right) \sum_{l_2=0}^\infty \sum_{m_2=-l_2}^{l_2} a_{l_2 m_2} Y_{l_2 m_2}\left(\hat{n}_2\right) \right\rangle_{\hat{n}_1\cdot \hat{n}_2 = \cos\theta} .$$

I understand that the spherical harmonics can be written in the form

$$ Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi) \propto P_{lm} \left(\cos\theta\right) e^{i m \phi} $$

(where $P_{lm}(x)$ are the [associated Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials)) and that $C_l$ should come out as

$$ C_l = \frac{1}{2l + 1} \sum_{m=-l}^l a_{lm} a_{l-m} $$

(though I could be off on this last piece). However, I am unsure of the mathematical steps involved in simplifying the four sums down to one. What identities, properties, or other insights will allow me to make this simplification?

Thanks!

Comment: I take it that by $\langle\cdot\rangle_{\hat n_1\cdot\hat n_2=\cos\theta}$ you mean an average over all pairs of direction vectors $\hat n_1$, $\hat n_2$ that form an angle $\theta$. But what do you mean by $\langle a_{lm}b_{lm}\rangle$? What are you averaging over in this case?

Comment: @joriki Good question. I actually was conflating a couple similar equations, but the short answer is that I was indeed off in writing that piece (it should be fixed now though). There are two relevant kinds of averages, which has contributed to my difficulties. One is the *cosmic mean*, which is the average of the results obtained by other observers in many points in space for given directions. However, we cannot actually measure the cosmic mean, so instead we average over all directions on the sky from a single vantage point.